# Alternative OAuth 2.0 Type Where The Client and Resource Owner Are The Same

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am building a application where I am both the client and resource owner (in OAuth's words). And this application would connect to a service - like Google - using OAuth 2. Because I'm building the application and I'm the only authenticated user using the system is myself, does this remove the requirement for a refresh token? Is there a support for this kind of situation in OAuth 2?

I ask becuase handling a refresh token makes the code more complex and I would want to avoid that if there is an alternative (but still secure) way.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry I did looks through the grant types and must have missed this one - or misunderstood it if I did. I'll see if anyone else posts otherwise I'll award to a answer if you submit this (if you care for that stuff). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OAuth 2.0 specification covers this use case with its [Client Credentials grant type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4):

> The client can request an access token using only its client credentials (or other supported means of authentication) when the client is requesting access to the protected resources under its control.